# iOS simulator throwing unable to parse JSON

Tags: javascript, json, appendchild

I'm getting an error thrown from the code shown below. However, its strange because if I run this .html file locally in a browser like Safari, Chrome, or Firefox I don't get an error and the program works fine. Its when I load up the .html file in my iOS Simulator I get a JavaScript Error: undefined SyntaxError: Unable to parse JSON string.

I would assume I have something undefined but why will the error only come up on the iOS Emulator?

```
function getData () {
    toggleControls("on");
    if(localStorage.length === 0){
        alert("There are no items saved in Local Storage.");
    }
    var makeDiv = document.createElement('div');
    makeDiv.setAttribute("id", "items");
    var makeList = document.createElement('ul');
    makeDiv.appendChild(makeList);
    document.body.appendChild(makeDiv);
    for(var i=0, len=localStorage.length; i<len; i++){
        var makeli = document.createElement('li');
        makeList.appendChild(makeli);
        var key = localStorage.key(i);
        var value = localStorage.getItem(key);
        var obj = JSON.parse(value);
        var makeSubList = document.createElement('ul');
        makeli.appendChild(makeSubList);
        for(var n in obj){
            var makeSubList = document.createElement('li');
            makeSubList.appendChild(makeSubli);
            var optSubText = obj[n][0]+" "+[n][1];
            makeSubli.innerHTML = optSubText;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What was making this not work correctly was garbage data that was save in the application im making, it was looking for my data in a particular format.